# Can ‘on one’s own’ be an adjective, implying 'while one is alone'?

Tags: phrases

Can this phrase ‘on one’s own’ be used as a post-modifying adjective phrase like below, meaning ‘while one is alone’?

> The gangsters wanted to catch him **on his own**.

Comment: [Yes](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/on_one%27s_own)

Comment: "On his own" is a prepositional phrase, however, so it can't be an adjective phrase, only an adverbial phrase that functions as an adjective phrase. You can substitute an adjective for "on his own": _The gangsters wanted to catch him {**alone** / **red-handed**}_, which shows that the adjective and the adverb phrase have the same function, _viz._ to post-modify "_him_". Does it matter whether the phrase **is** an adjective or an adverb? If so, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/own?q=one%27s%20own#own__26) define *'on one's own'* as *unaccompanied by others; alone or unaided*. So, that also means *'while one is alone'*, as you have already guessed.

> The gangsters wanted to catch him *on his own* (that is, *while he was unaccompanied by others* or *while he was alone*.